# Google sheet : passing value/data from cell as parameter in google script function

Tags: google-sheets

I add script using tools/script editor. I add my simple popup function :

```
function test(){
  Browser.msgBox('This is test')
}
```

Then in google sheet, i add an image as button and attach the script 'test'.

It works fine, but i want to pass value from a cell. How can i do it?

For example, i modify the function as follow :

```
function test(val){
  Browser.msgBox('This is test. Value is '+val)
}
```

if i want to pass value from cell B4 --> `test(B4)`. How to do it properly ? i'm not allowed to include the parameter B4 when assigning script to image/button. It will say 'script could not be found'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JohnA's solution is correct, but I want to add something to it. I recommend this enhancement to avoid modifying your script every now and then when you want pass another cell as a parameter.

#### Approach:

- Store the cell notation you want to pass on a specific cell. (e.g. "B4" in A1)
- Get the value of A1 and access the value of that cell notation.

#### Code:

```
function test() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // cell holds the range you want printed
  cell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  // value now holds the value of the range we got from the cell
  value = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(value);
}
```

#### Sheet:

[image: sheet]

#### B4:

[image: b4]

#### B5:

[image: b5]

#### Note:

- Everytime you change the value of the A1, it will print that cell's value.
- It will not behave properly when you write an invalid range in A1. (`Exception: Range not found`)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you can specify a parameter if calling the custom function as a formula in the sheet, but not as attached to a script when a button is pressed. We do not even included the parentheses when we assign a script.

If the customer function always wants to use the value of B4, you can modify your script the get the value from that cell.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var val = sheet.getRange("B4");
```